# GROUP BY one column or another (transitive relation)

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb

I have two columns that could be used as user unique identity: SSN and email, for instance. I need to `GROUP BY` all users that could be unified by one of this columns.

```
id  | name      | ssn     | email
1     John        123       john@test.com
2     Doe         123       john.doe@test.com
3     Mr          NULL      john.doe@test.com
```

All of above rows are basically for the same user. ID #1 and #2 have same `ssn` column. ID #2 and #3 have same `email`. So ID #1 and #3 are the same. A transitive relation.

If I use something like `GROUP BY ssn, email` it actually will not works.

**What I do expects:**

Supposing that I do something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(users.id) AS ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users.email) AS emails_used_by_user
FROM users

GROUP BY TRANSITIVE(ssn, email) # Example
```

It will returns a single row like:

```
ids   | emails_used_by_user
1,2,3   john@test.com,john.doe@test.com
```

Because ID #1, #2 and #3 are the same user, based on SSN and email information.

Comment: (1) What results do you want?  (2) This sounds like you need a recursive CTE.

Comment: You want to merge the rows belonging to the same user? If so, how do you decide what to do with the values of `ssn` and `email` for that user?

Comment: GROUP BY is for aggregation (finding sums, counts, averages, etc....); what are you trying to do? And what should happen if there is a row with `ssn 456` and `email john.doe@test.com`?

Comment: For the sample data in your question, edit the question and show the result you are expecting.

Comment: Okay, I have added an example result.

Comment: Is `ssn` always `NULL` in the rows that should be identified by email?

Comment: Can there be rows with the same email but different non-null ssn? Should these be grouped together?

Comment: You are not clearly saying what you want. You are just writing fragmemts. A row is in the result when what is true?

Comment: @philipxy All the rows are in the result. The issue is with how they're grouped together.

Comment: @Barmar What I meant was, when is a row that is typed by the desired output heading in the result as opposed to not being in the result. Ie when is a row value (ids, emails_used_by_user) in the result. PS The post doesn't even ask a question. It seems like maybe they want to ask for a query that would input the first table & output the last table but they don't actually say even that.

Comment: I thought he made it pretty clear that rows from the original table are grouped together in the result if they have the same email or the same ssn, and the question is implicitly "How do I do this?"

Comment: @Barmar The post isn't clear, we just think that there's a most likely thing they want that would generate that unclear post. PS When you write "All the rows are in the result" & "rows from the original table are grouped together in the result" you don't mean that input rows are in the result or even are subrows of the result, you are 'abusing language', which is helpful for brevity when everybody involved knows what they are all talking about but is an impediment when they don't. The reason I made my 1st comment is that answering (a clear version of) it leads to clearly saying what one wants.

Comment: I can't think of a better way to describe it myself, maybe that's why I consider his question acceptably clear. The question isn't about selecting, it's about grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` to get the SSN from another row with the same email when the SSN is null.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u1.id) AS ids, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u1.email) AS emails
FROM users AS u1
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON u1.ssn IS NULL AND u1.email = u2.email AND u1.id != u2.id
GROUP BY IFNULL(u1.ssn, u2.ssn)
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhAuCXjoKrQ34BXkHi16Pq/0)

Comment: You have understanded the problem, and your solution works in that case. But if I duplicate rows it will fail. But you give me a vision of how to solve this problem. Thanks! https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4J3cvxSCDzTqDFnLtdHirn/0

Comment: I asked questions above about duplicates. I'm not sure if there's a good solution if there are ambiguous combinations. If you can come up with a better solution, you should post your own answer.